# How to Add Pivoting to find Inverse

Tags: python, matrix, matrix-inverse

The code I created is supposed to calculate the inverse of a given matrix, I got it to work for an array with 2 rows and 2 columns, but when I do a matrix of 3 rows and 3 columns it returns an error. I need to add pivoting to fix this but am unsure on how to go about it. My code is below:

```
import numpy as np

def myInverse(A):
                                                #input: A = a sqaure matrix
                                                #output: C = the inverse of A
    nr,nc = A.shape                                 # set the shape of the matrix
    B = np.concatenate ((A,np.eye(nr)), axis=1)     # adds the identity matrix of number of rows A to the orginal so Gauss Elimination is possible
    nr,nc = B.shape                                 # redifine nr,nc in terms of matrix B
    for r in range (nr):                            # iterates through all rows of matrix
        scale =  B[r][r]                                    
        for c in range (nc):
            B[r][c] = B[r][c]/scale
        for rr in range (nr):
            if rr != r:
                scale = B[rr][r]
                for c in range (r,nc):
                    B[rr][c] = B[rr][c] - scale*B[r][c]
    C = B[:,nr:nc]
    return C

A = np.array([[2.0,1,-1],[2,1,-2],[1,-1,1]])
iA = myInverse(A)
print(iA)
```